# Extraer los valores de un comboBox en C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Buenas tardes tengo un inconveniente con respecto a obtener los valores, no los items de un ComboBox. Este ComboBox tiene valores guardados que son los nombres de las provincias y los nombres están almacenados en una base de datos SQL Server en la tabla Provincias:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_provincia(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    nombre_provincia varchar (50) not null,
    region varchar (50) not null,
    poblacion numeric (8) not null,
    extension numeric (8,2) not null,
    estado char default 'A'
);
```

Aquí está la estructura de creación de la tabla provincias
Ahora en un formulario tengo el ComboBox en donde extraigo los nombres de todas las provincias guardadas en la base de datos, básicamente extraigo los nombres de las provincias y los muestro en el ComboBox. Lo que necesito es de alguna manera extraer los id de cada una de las provincias que solicite cuando seleccione una opción del ComboBox. Un ejemplo que seleccione "Esmeraldas" y que en una caja de texto me muestre su id respectivo no el valor del ítem del ComboBox sino el id respectivo de esa provincia:

```
private void LlenarComboProvincia()
{
    try
    {
        cmb_Provincia.DataSource = obj_provincia.getListadoProvincias();
        cmb_Provincia.DisplayMember = "nombre_provincia";
        cmb_Provincia.ValueMember = "id";
        cmb_Provincia.SelectedIndex = 0; //Muestra en la caja de texto
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error al cargar datos de provincia" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Aquí es donde lleno el ComboBox cuando inicio el formulario, pero si necesito obtener el valor del id de la provincia y que se muestre en una caja de texto:

```
private void cmb_Provincia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var indice = cmb_Provincia.SelectedIndex;
    MessageBox.Show(""+indice);
}
```

Aquí quería saber que índices salían pero son los índices del ComboBox no el id de cada provincia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me gustaría saber o que alguien me ayude a obtener esos id. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Pon este código en el **evento SelectionChangeCommitted** del **ComboBox**:

```
var objeto = ((Provincia)cmb.SelectedItem);
```

Lo que haces aquí es obtener la **entidad Provincia** que seleccionas del **ComboBox** casteando al tipo de datos indicado, aquí yo asumo que tu tipo de datos se llama **Provincia**, pero tú quizá tengas otro nombre. Posteriormente para acceder al id harías:

```
var id = objeto.Id;
```